# Not exactly sure why my recursive linked list deletion function works? Would love an explanation

Tags: c++, pointers, singly-linked-list

I wrote a program, and it works, but I dont think it should. Can someone explain why it works?

I have a singly linked list. This is for a project so I cant post direct code, but Ill change the problem a bit

Lets say my linked list is a list of numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5

I need to scan the list and delete any duplicates, so I need to remove one of the 4's. And I need to do it via recursion.

The function I am writing has its argument/parameter as the pointer to the beginning of the list, I shall call this **pointer**

```
//Base cases up here
if (pointer->value == pointer->next->value){
    *toDelete = pointer;
     pointer = pointer->next;
     delete toDelete;
     recur the function
} else recur(pointer->next);
```

Now this code works, and I dont think it should because I never connect the previous node to the one after the node i delete. yet when I look at the result all proper nodes are connected and all the ones that were supposed to be removed are removed. Am I misunderstanding something here? does **pointer = pointer->next** do more than just point **pointer** to address of the next node?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, can you post the full code? We cannot tell what you do or don't do if you are leaving out some parts.

Comment: If you (*really*) want a singly linked list data structure, then for the love of $DEITY, just use `std::forward_list` and be done with it. Please. Don't reinvent the wheel badly - please. Even better, just use `std::vector`; it's likely to do better in real life conditions more or less always (regardless of algorithmic complexity etc and other theoretical things).

Comment: @JesperJuhl unfortunately I have to do it as the assignment dictates. Not my choice.

Comment: @SamirAguiar This is how we learn, dont we :) Observe something, then question how it works :)

Comment: @Duxa: in case you are doing an assignment; please let us know in your question. It's helps to prevent chatty comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now this code works, and I dont think it should because I never connect the previous node to the one after the node i delete.

That's correct. Your function might appear to work but it is really showing signs of undefined behavior. You need to use:

```
if ( pointer->next != nullptr && pointer->value == pointer->next->value){
    auto toDelete = pointer->next;
    pointer->next = pointer->next->next;
    delete toDelete;

    // Recurse with the same pointer since you might have 4 4 4
    // in the original list.
    recur(pointer);
}
else {    
   recur(pointer->next);
}
```

Comment: Yes thank you. That is what I was thinking about writing (plus handing removal from beginning and end of list), but I just wasnt sure why the heck my implementation worked :/